# Laravel project on 000webhostapp controller doesnot exist

Tags: php, laravel, web-hosting

I uploaded my laravel project version 8 to 000webhostapp I did all the required configurations . The project is running normally on my localhost pc but when using it on 000webhost the views are appearing normally but when there is a function that want to access controller i am getting this error

```
Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException
Target class [App\http\Controllers\ScheduleController] does not exist.
```

Knowing that everything is working normally on my pc

**Route**

```
Route::get('/schedules','App\http\Controllers\ScheduleController@openPage');
```

**ScheduleController**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\schedule;
Use File;
class ScheduleController extends Controller
{
```

Comment: verify all your files have uploaded properly esp. routes and controllers. if not we are going to need more information.

Comment: everything was uploaded properly , and please tell me information like what so i can update my uestion with the sifficient information

Comment: try clearing route cache, view cache & running compose autoload related commands.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`App\http\Controllers\ScheduleController` is not the same as `App\Http\Controllers\ScheduleController`. Your Controllers are in the `App\Http\Controllers` namespace. With the lowercase `http` it is looking for a folder named `http` not `Http` to load this class.

Adjust the route definition to use the FQCN in the correct case:

```
Route::get('/schedules','App\Http\Controllers\ScheduleController@openPage');
```

You probably went from a case insensitive to a case sensitive filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

Check your route and controller, maybe you need to execute:

```
php artisan route:clear
```